# Gerar string seguramente aleatória em PHP

Tags: php, criptografia, random

Como, usando a linguagem PHP, gerar uma string, preferencialmente com tamanho configurável, *aleatória o suficiente para ser usada em rotinas que lidam com criptografia* e que por questões de segurança **não podem ser** insuficientemente aleatória?

Caso proponha mais de uma solução, preferencialmente explicitar qual considera que é mais aleatória, possivelmente com **referências adicionais externas**. Soluções que envolvem mais de uma fonte de gerador de aleatoriedade também são bem vindas, em especial se acompanhadas de explicação de vantagens, a exemplo de reduzir problemas com um sistema operacional explicitamente alterado por uma NSA da vida para gerar menos caos na hora de produzir aleatoriedade.

Mesmo que duas pessoas proponham o mesmo código, caso uma destas explique melhor ou prove com exemplos reais a dispersão de valores, será considerado como melhor resposta. Não basta copiar e colar código, deverá dissertar porque é uma boa solução.

Soluções que acessam diretamente um recurso do sistema operacional, usando por exemplo `shell_exec`, embora não sejam desejáveis, também são bem vindas com explicação de em que contexto seriam vantajosas a exemplo de versões de PHP mais antigas ou que não tem um módulo PHP específico que permitiria usar uma rotina mais apropriada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando se trata de questões de criptografia/segurança, o ideal é usar ferramentas feitas mesmo para isso.

Um exemplo no PHP é a [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](https://www.php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes), uma função que foi feita para gerar números aleatórios (com um nº configurável de bytes).

```
$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length, $strong);
if (!$strong) {
    //Tratar o erro
    exit();
}
$hex = bin2hex($bytes);
```

Esta biblioteca nem sempre está disponível, o que pode ser problemático.

Em Linux, o `/dev/random` é um "ficheiro" especial que permite extraír bytes aleatórios.
O `/dev/urandom` é muito semelhante ao `/dev/random`, embora tenham comportamentos ligeiramente diferentes quando o computador fica "sem entropia", isto é, não tem mais dados para ir buscar para usar como fonte de números aleatórios.

Supostamente, [tanto quanto se sabe](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key), usar este ficheiro serve para efeitos de segurança.

```
$file = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');
if (!$file) {
    // Falhou
    exit();
}
$bytes = fread($file, $length);
fclose($file);
$hex = bin2hex($bytes);
```

Esta segunda solução tem a desvantagem de não estar disponível em Windows.

**O que não serve**

`rand` e `mt_rand` não foram feitos a pensar em criptografia, pelo que não servem.
A função `mt_rand` é descrita pela documentação como "melhor" que a `rand`, mas ainda assim tem este [aviso](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php):

> Caution
>
> This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and
> should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a
> cryptographically secure value, consider using
> openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.

Em Português:

> Cuidado
>
> Esta função não gera valores criptograficamente seguros, e não deve
> ser usada para efeitos criptográficos. Se precisar de um valor
> criptograficamente seguro, pondere usar openssl_random_pseudo_bytes em
> vez disto.

A função `uniqid` também não serve (veja [o aviso na própria documentação](http://pt2.php.net/uniqid), o aviso não está disponível em todas as línguas):

> This function does not create random nor unpredictable string. This
> function must not be used for security purposes. Use cryptographically
> secure random function/generator and cryptographically secure hash
> functions to create unpredictable secure ID.

Em português:

> Esta função não cria strings aleatórias nem imprevisíveis. Esta função
> não pode ser usada para efeitos de segurança. Use geradores de números
> aleatórios seguros e funções de hash criptograficamente seguras para
> criar IDs imprevisíveis seguros.

A hash(md5, sha, etc.) de um valor que não é suficientemente aleatório para efeitos criptográficos continua a não ser criptograficamente segura.

Answer (score 2):

> **PHP 7 <sub><sub>ou superior.</sub></sub>**

Você pode utilizar o `random_bytes()`, ele é criptograficamente seguro e utiliza o `/dev/urandom`:

```
$numero_de_bytes = 12;
$random = random_bytes($numero_de_bytes);
```

Para ter um dado em *hexadecimal* você terá que utilizar, neste caso, o `bin2hex`:

```
echo bin2hex($random);
```

Isso irá ter como saída 24 *letras humanamente compreensíveis* aleatórias. ;)

---

> **Libsodium <sub><sub>possivelmente já embutido no PHP 7.2 com outra sintaxe.</sub></sub>**

O [`Libsodium`](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php) é uma biblioteca [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/) que é uma das mais seguras e que *deve* ser inseridas no PHP 7.2, *com alteração na sintaxe*.

```
$numero_de_bytes = 12;
$random = \Sodium\randombytes_buf($numero_de_bytes);
```

Já o `Libsodium` possui uma função que substitui o `bin2hex` original do PHP, porque ele é vulnerável a ataques *side-channel*, então utilize:

```
echo \Sodium\bin2hex($random);
```

Uma outra opção é utilizar:

```
echo \Sodium\bin2hex(
          \Sodium\randombytes_buf($numero_de_bytes)
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

Já existe no PHP 5.3.0 ou superior rotina especifica para isso.

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php

Usa o Openssl para gerar as strings, com um parâmetro sendo o tamanho e o outro um booleano que retorna True se for considerado seguro o suficiente para uso com criptografia.

Referencia ao site da OpenSSL sobre o funcionamento da mesma.

http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers

E se quiser testar você pode pegar os resultados da função converter para binário e rodar uma suíte de teste estatística para validar o quão aleatório são os valores gerados usando o Cryptographic Toolkit da NIST.

Comment: talvez vc devesse colocar o código dessa rotina na sua resposta, fica mais facil das pessoas verem e se um dia o link deixar de funcionar sua resposta ainda será válida.

Comment: Concordo com você que poderia ter colocado um exemplo, mas não tinha tempo para escrever e testar uma rotina, que poderia ficar desatualizada com tempo e atualizações na API do PHP. O link é direto para pagina da API do PHP, de onde não é permitido reproduzir o conteudo do site, logo não poderia copiar e colar o exemplo aqui. Mas agradeço a sugestoes e vou levar em consideração para as minhas proximas respostas.

Comment: @math Existe outro problema de licença, todo conteudo colocado no site é automaticamente licenciado pela cc by-sa 3.0, a não ser que o codigo fosse feito por mim, só poderia postar algum codigo pronto na web se a licença fosse compativel. O que no caso do site do PHP não é, porque o conteudo do site deles tem Copyright e não é permitido a copia de todo ou parte do mesmo. Logo, cuidado é necessario ao se postar codigo de terceiros aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Há várias formas de se gerar strings "aleatórias" e, geralmente, a questão chaves nos algoritmos é a *seed* que será a fonte da entropia e o algoritmo que irá gerar a string aleatória.

Uma forma bem simples de gerar uma string pseudo-aleatória em PHP é:

```
$size = 2; // até 40
$seed = time(); // time() só para exemplo!
echo substr(sha1($seed), 40 - min($size,40));
```

A vantagem é que é bem simples, mas não é tão aleatório assim. Mas resolve se for para uma aplicação simples.

---

Outra solução é usar a função mt_rand() que utiliza o algoritmo [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) como gerador de pseudo-aleatoriedade. Com essa função você pode gerar strings pseudo-aleatórias com maior qualidade. No entanto, para alguns casos ela é pode ser bem lenta (comparada a rand() que usa [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)).

Existem outras variações da MT (melhores até), a SFMT (utiliza SSE) e MTGP (otimizada para GPUs), mas não sei se há implementações delas para PHP.

Você pode usar o seguinte para gerar suas strings com MT assim:

```
function random_str_mt($size) 
{
    $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'));

    $key = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < ($size+10); $i++) 
    {
        $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
    }

    return substr($key, 0, $size);
}

echo random_str_mt(20);
```

No exemplo acima, o substr() quebra um pedaço da string gerada para melhorar a qualidade do resultado.

---

Para criptografia a melhor solução é utilizar funções próprias para esse fim. Se você utilizar PGP a função `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`. Por exemplo:

```
function random_str_ossl($size) 
{
    return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($size));
}

echo random_str_ossl(20);
```

No Windows, a chamada do `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` é consideravelmente lenta em algumas versões do PHP (acho que as mais novas já corrigiram isso).

---

Outra alternativa é utilizar o `dev/urandom` ou `/dev/random`. Como nunca testei, vou deixar apenas esse [link](http://codeascraft.com/2012/07/19/better-random-numbers-in-php-using-devurandom/).