# php duvida como gerar dez senha aleatórias

Tags: php

Ola tenho esse codigo que é parecido o que eu quero.
bom ele gerar numero de 1 a 10
e seguencia tipo:
 1
2
 e ai vai.

Gostaria que no lugar do numero, que ele gerasse senhas aleatórias
tipo:

w3e4r5

g6t5e4

e ai vai.

```html
<?php 
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    echo "$x";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Já leu a discussão [Gerar string seguramente aleatória em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5979)?

Comment: Ou ainda a [Criar senha aleatória diferente para cada registro em loop](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56732)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O **PHP 7** possui uma função chamada **random_bytes** que se usar convertendo de binário pra hex, gera umas string parecidas com o que vc quer.

```
<?php
// Usando a função random_bytes do PHP 7
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) 
{
    echo bin2hex(random_bytes(3)) . "<br>"; // gera uma string pseudo-randômica criptograficamente segura de 6 caracteres
} 
?>
```

Exemplo de output(muda toda vez que roda o script):

```
eb5a35
ce5121
d5c514
e4eec4
48d781
52367c
ae39cd
5ef0ff
dfe681
0ac13f
```

Referência:
https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.random-bytes.php

---

Mas caso ainda não use PHP7 ou não tenha gostado da opção com hexadecimais utilizado pela função existente no PHP7, uma técnica interessante que vi no Stack Overflow em inglês e adaptei aqui é com o uso do **str_shuffle**, uma função que embaralha strings aleatoriamente. Esta função está presente no PHP a partir do **PHP 4**.

```
<?php


// Usando str_shuffle (mistura strings aleatoriamente)
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) 
{

    //Inclua todos os caracteres que gostaria que aparecessem nas strings geradas
    $caracteres_q_farao_parte = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    $password = substr( str_shuffle($caracteres_q_farao_parte), 0, 6 );     

    echo $password . "<br>";

} 


?>
```

Exemplo de output(sairão diferentes toda vez que rodar o script):

```
yc7dj6
g57rt0
prwgdn
hctvog
d2l0cq
r78fp1
0z6c4e
95m8fa
19bnx5
vyw8p6
```

Referência: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-shuffle.php

Comment: Se estiver no PHP inferior ao 7 pode utilizar a implementação https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat, para utilizar o `random_bytes`, como descrito na documentação, é a melhor opção.

Answer (score 3):

Se você realmente se preocupa "*exageradamente*" com segurança deverá utilizar o [LibSodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php), ele possui ambos os recursos, para gerar e para converter para hexadecimal, estou respondendo isto [baseado no que respondi aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188091/15089).

```
for($gerar = 10; $gerar > 0; $gerar--){
    echo \Sodium\bin2hex( \Sodium\randombytes_buf(3) );
}
```

O `bin2hex` original do PHP, como respondido por @Antonio Alexandre, é vulnerável a ataques *side-channel*, enquanto o `\Sodium\bin2hex` é mais resistente e este tipo de ataque.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está uma solução

```
     function randomPassword() {
        $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
        $pass = array(); 
        $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; 
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
            $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
            $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
        }
        return implode($pass); 
    }

  for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
      echo randomPassword() .'<br>';
    }
```